# Adding TinyMCE custom buttons when using teeny_mce_before_init

Tags: tinymce, buttons

I'm using the following code to produce a different TinyMCE bar to the default WordPress setup:

```
if (function_exists('wp_tiny_mce')) {

    add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "add_myplugin_tinymce_plugin");
    add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_myplugin_button');

    add_filter('teeny_mce_before_init', create_function('$a', '
      $a["theme"] = "advanced";
      $a["skin"] = "wp_theme";
      $a["height"] = "75";
      $a["width"] = "800";
      $a["onpageload"] = "";
      $a["mode"] = "exact";
      $a["elements"] = "elm1, elm2";
      $a["editor_selector"] = "mceEditor";
      $a["plugins"] = "safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker";

      $a["forced_root_block"] = false;
      $a["force_br_newlines"] = true;
      $a["force_p_newlines"] = false;
      $a["convert_newlines_to_brs"] = true;

      return $a;'));

    wp_tiny_mce(true);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to work a basic custom button in there?

All I need is a straightforward button which prints [ph_min] into the editor area.

I've tried using the following filters to no avail:

```
function register_tcustom_button($buttons)
{
    array_push($buttons, "|", "highlight");
    return $buttons;
}

function add_tcustom_tinymce_plugin($plugin_array)
{
    $plugin_array['highlight'] = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/sf-tinyMCE-custom-buttons/mce/min_max_buttons/editor_plugin.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}

add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "add_tcustom_tinymce_plugin");
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_tcustom_button');
```

Is there any way of doing this, or will I have to use write a manual TinyMCE init which isn't supported by WP?

Comment: Do you have the `editor_plugin.js` in place?

Comment: Yeah, it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you have already registered your shortcode. Now what we need to do is to initiate the Button. Once the shortcode is registered [ph_min]
 let's check if user can use rich editing:

```
function add_highlight_button() {
   if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') )
     return;
   if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true') {
     add_filter('mce_external_plugins', 'add_tcustom_tinymce_plugin');
     add_filter('mce_buttons', 'register_tcustom_button');
   }
}

add_action('init', 'add_highlight_button');
```

Now lets register the button

```
function register_tcustom_button( $buttons ) {
 array_push( $buttons, "|", "highlight" );
 return $buttons;
}
```

Now let's register TinyMCE plugin

```
function add_tcustom_tinymce_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
   $plugin_array['mylink'] = get_bloginfo( 'template_url' ) . '/script/mybuttons.js';
   return $plugin_array;
}
```

And this is for the JS file called from the previous function:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.highlight', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
            ed.addButton('highlight', {
                title : 'Highlight',
                image : url+'/yourlink.png',
                onclick : function() {
                     ed.selection.setContent('[ph_min]');

                }
            });
        },
        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        },
    });
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('highlight', tinymce.plugins.highlight);
})();
```

That's about it.

Comment: Thanks for that.

However, when I'm using the "teeny_mce_before_init" (to provide myself with a small-sized, one toolbar MCE editor on exact elements), your code (nor my own) doesn't work.

It appears as if running the "teeny_mce_before_init" filter means the other MCE-related filters won't run.

If I use your (or my own) code without running "teeny_mce_before_init", I can view the page's source code and see the external plugin being registered. When I add the "teeny_mce_before_init" filter, there is no such registration.

Comment: This example didn't compile at a first copy/pasta (too many objects called `highlight`). I ended up writing a working one and [added to the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/mce_external_plugins#Creating_a_shortcode_and_a_tag_button).