# Prevent the Editor From Moving My &nbsp;

Tags: tinymce, html-editor

I know variations on this have been asked all over the WordPress world, but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<a name="title-slug">&nbsp;</a>My Section Title
```

I find that if the anchor tag is empty, browsers tend not to scroll precisely to it when the name fragment is added to the URL. So, I want to have the mark up shown above. The problem is that when I enter that markup into the "Text" tab of the editor and switch to "Visual" mode, TinyMCE changes it to this:

```
<a name="title-slug"></a>&nbsp;My Section Title
```

I have a filter on `tiny_mce_before_init` similar to the one [shown here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/55242/9802) where I set the `entities` key to allow for `&nbsp;`, but I have no idea why it's moving the space outside of the anchor tag.

I tried using the `extend_valid_elements` setting like this: `'a[name|class|id|text|href|style|target|rel|#text]'`, but that only made things worse (two `&nbsp;` where added after the anchor and it was still emptied). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about a `[nbsp num="2"]` shortcode? Num being the quantity of `&nbsp;`.

Comment: That could definitely work. It's one more thing to remember which isn't necessarily ideal, but it would save me from fighting with TinyMCE.

Comment: ... or maybe take it all into `[anchor name="title-slug"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple solution/workaround, but a Shortcode could be used. 
As [birgire noted](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/114596/prevent-the-editor-from-moving-my-nbsp#comment164315_114596), the whole anchor can be the Shortcode.

And for ease of use, [this article](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/how-to-make-shortcodes-user-friendly/) has a solution: adding a shortcode button in TinyMCE. You could have a dropdown with a selection of anchors, turning the fight in your favor ;) WP editor is really a PITA when it comes to this kind of characters/entities control.

And the best related [Shortcode -> TinyMCE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/20531/12615) that I found here at WPSE.